# How to set a maximum and minimum length for a post title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm designing a website in WordPress.

Can anyone help me on how to set a minimum and maximum length for a post title in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php write this code-

```
function max_title_length( $title ) {
$max = 20;
if( strlen( $title ) > $max ) {
return substr( $title, 0, $max ). " &hellip;";
} else {
return $title;
}
}
```

And then place the function wherever you want in your theme. For example, if you want to show shortened titles on your homepage, you want to place this code into your Main Index Template (index.php)

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length');
```

Or you can use built-in function: `wp_trim_words().`

Use this where you want to display your title with limited words-

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5 ); ?>
```

replace number 5 with whatever number of words you need to display.